# Can't display photos from absolute path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I developing one application in asp.net mvc and decided to store files into file system instead of database (I put just absolute path to files on db table). All files in developing phase I put into special dedicated folder inside app folder. After deployment on server I faced problem with IIS permissions and did't manage to save files. Then I decide to move mentioned folder with files to C:\Upload folder and everything was fine until I tried to get photos and display it with thickbox dialog widget (photo gallery). After some googling I conclude that asp.net mvc can display photos only from relative paths. What can I do now, is it storing in BLOBs only one solution?

**Update:**

*Model code*

```
public class PriloziViewModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }       
}
```

*Controller code:*

```
public ActionResult VijestiSlike(Int64 vijestID)
{
    var slike = from i in db.Slikes where i.FK_vijesti_id == vijestID select i;

    PriloziViewModel s = new PriloziViewModel();
    List<PriloziViewModel> slist = new List<PriloziViewModel>();

    foreach (var j in slike) {
        slist.Add(new PriloziViewModel()
                  {
                      FileName = j.naziv,
                      FilePath = j.link
                  });  
    }
    return View(slist);
}
```

*View code:*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.PriloziViewModel>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>        
         <a href="<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FilePath) %>" title="" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants">
         <img src="<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FilePath) %>" style="width:120px;height:80px;" alt="" /></a> 

<% } %>
```

Link is stored in database in a format C:\Uploads\Photo12345.jpg

Virtual directory (C:\Uploads) is also added on IIS.

Comment: What are you talking about? - *"After some googling I conclude that asp.net mvc can display photos only from relative paths"*, you need to google again.

Comment: your comment didn't help me at all

Comment: why save absolute paths into the database? that absolute path doesn't mean anything when it comes to the browser. it's not that asp.net mvc can't display images from absolute paths. Browser can't see `C:\Upload` folder on your server. For the website, absolute path begins with the domain name. In windows, absolute path begins with the drive letter. if you want to keep images in `C:\Upload` then create a virtual directory in IIS and save paths relative to that directory. or create an images folder within your website and give proper permissions to that folder so you can upload files to it.

Comment: @Amila It doesn't matter absolute, relative using blobs. Any of these scenarios can be handled but the fact is the OP hasn't posted a single line of code to help us help him.

Comment: @Lankymart the code is not the problem I will update my post.
I already tried with virtual directory and I mange to see photos from URL http://localhost:84/Upload/ but still cannot show them on aspx page using thickbox. As I already said I will post code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Code above is correct actually, after setup of Virtual Directory the only one thing I have changed is path in database. Correct format of path is /Uploads/Photo12345.jpg